# Import module lose first symbol in some word in CSV file after import

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

[Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/import) module of Drupal 6 lose first symbol in some word in CSV file after import.

Example. 
Before import:

[image]

After import:

[image]

In CSV file  word is "Refond", but after import - "efond".

Comment: Thanks! Now my problem is clarified?

Comment: yes, **PS: [On February 24th 2016, Drupal 6 will reach end of life and no longer be supported.](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)**